# Create Views independent of _Layout.cshtml

Tags: view, asp.net-core-mvc

I've got a view (e.g. `test1.cshtml`) from `Views/Home` that is dependent on `_Layout.cshml` held in `Views/Shared`.

Following the creation of a new view (e.g. `test2.cshtml`) from `Views/Sample`, I am noticing that `test2.cshtml` is still relying on `_Layout.cshml`, whereas I look for creating a view completely independent (e.g. different/nothing in common) from `_Layout.cshml`.

To achieve this task in ASP.NET Webforms, I was excluding the reference `MasterPageFile="~/xx.Master"` within `file.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Title="test2" Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/xxx.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="test2.aspx.cs"  %>
```

Thus, I am keen on learning an equivalent approach in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Thanks in advance, and best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that when you add a view, there will be the following _layout layout bar?

[image]

If you don't want to use it, you just need to add `Layout = null`:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}


<h1>This is test2 page!!</h1>
```

[Views in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. ```Layout = null``` has indeed solved the issue.